# How to configure the Dynamics CRM 2011 Outlook Client

Tags: outlook, client, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, outlook-addin

i have some problems configuring the outlook client for dynamics crm 2011. the crm-server runs on a dedicated server, that is not rechable from outside the network of my company (im using dynamics crm for my master thesis). i can only reach it from within our network and i have no problems to do so with the internet explorer and the web client.

when i start the config wizard of the outlook client, i am prompted to insert the url of the crm-server. when i type in the ip of it (including the port where the crm-server is installed), i get the response, that there is no communication possible (to the server).

i also tried to change the windows hosts-file and resolve the dns/server-name to put the servername into the field (instead of using the ip). but nothing can bring me further in the wizard. i cannot sign in to dynamics or select an organisation.

greets,
suutsch

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate for SuperUser or maybe ServerFault, but probably not StackOverflow since there's no programming question here.